# Get table view size of child view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uicontainerview

In `viewDidLoad` of my child view controller (`UITableViewController`) I'm getting the `contentSize.Height` after calling `layoutIfNeeded`. Than I set the `preferredContentSize` with these values. In `viewDidLoad` of my container (which holds this child) I also set the `preferredContentSize` based on the child's `preferredContentSize`. This works on iOS 8 but not on iOS 7.

I know that the `viewDidLoad` of the child view controller is called after the `viewDidLoad` of the container.

How do I get the table view size of the child or how can I force that the child view has layout its subviews before the container has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

In the child view controller I created a separate method which takes the values for the table view. Afterwards I set the preferred content size.

```
public void setDocumentList(List<string> documentList){
    this.documentList = documentList;

    this.TableView.ReloadData ();

    // adjust size for popover
    float height = TableView.ContentSize.Height;
    if (this.View.Bounds.Height > 0) {
        // limit the max size of the popover
        height = Math.Min (this.View.Bounds.Height, height);
    }
    this.PreferredContentSize = new SizeF (320f, height);
}
```

In my container I have a similar function, but here I only set the preferred content size.

```
public void setDocumentList(List<string> documentList){
    documentListController.setDocumentList (documentList);
    this.PreferredContentSize = documentListController.PreferredContentSize;

    // some autolayout constraints ...
}
```

This kind of works. I get the correct values, but the values of the popover are not correct in the beginning. If someone is wondering this is the C# language. I'm still open for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the layout request after all views have loaded:

```
// In the container
-(void) viewDidLoad {

    // ...

    [self.view performSelector:@selector(setNeedsLayout) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but the `contentSize` is still empty in the child and so the container get the zero values. It seems that in iOS 7 the view controller is not ready yet (not calculated the frames). In `viewDidAppear` I can query the `contentSize` but that's too late.

Comment: Did you try using `layoutSubviews` instead of `layoutIfNeeded`? If that doesn't work, you may need to calculate the height manually...

Comment: Now I tried it with `layoutSubviews` in `viewDidLoad` of my child view controller. I still get the same result (zero values). I think I'll try to calculate the height manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can load the tableView of the child by calling viewDidLoad of the child in the parent, and forcing the tableview to layout.

```
// Parent.m
[Child view];
[self layoutParentViewsOrDoSomething];

// Child.m

-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self layoutSubviews];
// or [tableView reloadData]... 
}
```